# Disable default ugly poster image in html5 video tag on android

Tags: android, html, html5-video

On android, using html5 video tag to load a video, before video loads, the placeholder image is a grayish image with a big "play" icon on it, suppose I don't have a poster image for the video so I couldn't replace it, is there any way I could disable the ugly one?

Answer (score 9):

I know this question is old, but I was looking for the answer to this. It turns out that `WebChromeClient` has a `getDefaultVideoPoster` method. So you can do something like:

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    @Override public Bitmap getDefaultVideoPoster() {
        final Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1, 1, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        // Use whatever color you want here. You could probably use a transparent color
        canvas.drawARGB(255, 0, 0, 0);
        return bitmap;
    }
});
```

I wouldn't necessarily make new bitmaps for every possible time this method could be called, but I'm sure you get the idea.

Comment: `canvas.drawARGB(255, 0, 0, 0);`

Comment: one more suggestion: if you want this poster to be transparent, you should create Bitmap with alpha channel: Bitmap.createBitmap(1, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444)

Comment: Any chance to do this with pure CSS?

Comment: this method is used when the video is not playing and you want to replace the element with poster image.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `poster` attribute to your `<video>` tag to skip the ugly pixelated default `android-webview-video-poster` image. A transparent PNG or GIF or an empty SVG work.